# Wordpress and Cloudflare: how to update (cached?) images

Tags: wordpress, image, cloudflare

I have my blog (wordpress) web site hosted at bluehost.com. A few months ago I decided to enable Cloudflare (through CPanel).

It's all working well (and I am seeing better overall performance etc) BUT I have a small issue I am dealing with.

I posted this blog some 10 days ago: http://it20.info/2016/01/why-docker-containers-and-docker-oss-docker-inc/

A few days later I had to change picture #2 (of 3) to tweak it a bit. The old picture says "Unikernel" in the red rectangle and the new picture (I uploaded) says "Unikernel/vm".

Note that inside the blog post I make an external reference to the picture (in the html code):

http://www.it20.info/misc/pictures/WhyDocker-ContainersAndDockerOSS-DockerInc2.jpg

If you point STRAIGHT to the picture you will see the new version (so I know I have updated it properly).

However the blog post still shows the old picture (as if Cloudflare is caching it indefinitely).

If in the blog post I right click on the image and do a "view image" (Firefox) it points to: http://i0.wp.com/www.it20.info/misc/pictures/WhyDocker-ContainersAndDockerOSS-DockerInc2.jpg?resize=640%2C392

(which shows the OLD image).

Funny enough if I remove the "?resize=640%2C392" it shows the proper picture.

I am trying to figure out a proper procedure to 1) write a blog post that refers to pictures as external links 2) possibly update said picture via an FTP upload and 3) have Cloudflare render the updated picture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem could be that query string after the image URL:

```
?resize=640%2C392
```

In CloudFlare, go to the caching settings and check if your current caching level is standard. If yes try changing to either no query string or ignore query string.

As far as a proper proceedure for future posts where images could change, as an alternative to purging all your site files in CloudFlare, or selectively purging just the image file in question, woudl it be feasible for you to simply change the name of the updated image file, or keep the same name but upload it to a different directory?  And of course update the image src in your HTML as well.

Good luck

Comment: thanks @david but that didn't seem to do a lot of difference. I have set the caching to "No Query String", I updated the picture again (like 4 hours ago) but connecting to the blog doesn't show the new picture. Now even removing the query doesn't bring up the new picture. To bring up the new pic I need to remove the "i0.wp.com" at the beginning of the URL. What works for me is a "PURGE OF ALL FILES". I may resort to this (not too worried about losing all the cache). Tks.

Comment: Update: a manual single file purge seems to be working too. I thought CloudFlare would do it on its own if a new file that invalidates the cache is detected)